# Inversion inequalities

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

Do there exist $n$ permutations $(\pi_i; 1 \le i \le n)$ of $[k]$ such that for any transposition $\sigma = (j, l)$, $1 \le j, l \le k$,
\begin{equation}
\label{1}
(*) \quad \sum_{i = 1}^n inv(\pi_i \circ \sigma) > \sum_{i = 1}^n inv(\pi_i),
\end{equation}
where $inv(\pi_i)$ is the number of inversions of $\pi_i$,
but
\begin{equation}
(**) \quad \sum_{i = 1}^n inv(\pi_i \circ \pi) \le \sum_{i = 1}^n inv(\pi_i) \quad \mbox{for some permutation } \pi \neq id ?
\end{equation}
The answer is no for n = 1 and 2, since $inv(\pi_i \circ \sigma) = inv(\pi) \pm 1$ for any adjacent transposition $\sigma$. In these cases, $(*)$ implies that $\pi_i = id$ and $(**)$ is automatically true. The answer also seems to be negative for $\pi$ a permutation of adjacent three elements, e.g. $(2,3,1)$.
I want to know if any positive or negative result holds in general.

Comment: Right. I want to know if one can construct $\pi_i$ for which such $\pi$ exists.

Comment: The notion of inversion I am familiar with is different. Inv(1,2) is different from inv(1,3) for two transpositions, and the +-1 property you cite does not hold. How are you computing Inv? Gerhard "Maybe I Got It Backwards?" Paseman, 2019.04.23.

Comment: Right, I mean for adjacent transposition.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest $k$ when such permutations exist is $k=4$. Namely, the set of $\pi_i$ given by
$$\big\{\  [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 3],$$
$$ [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 3, 2], [4, 2, 1, 3]\ \big\}$$
and $\pi = [2, 3, 4, 1]$ do the job. In fact, the total number of inversions in this set is decreased by 5 when the elements are multiplied by $\pi$, while multiplying them by any transposition increases the total number of inversions by at least 1.

---

**ADDED.** A smaller set example for the same $\pi = [2, 3, 4, 1]$: 
$$\{ [1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3] \}.$$